# What path to use for redirect in AWS Application Load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-elb

I'm reading the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html#redirect-actions) for setting up an HTTP to HTTPS redirect in the AWS Application Load Balancer but I cannot understand what to put as path expression (by the green arrow in the image):

[image: aws screenshot]

One guess would be: `http://#{host}:#{port}?/#{path}?#{query}?`or maybe `http://*` or maybe something else? For a beginner like me the documentation isn't all that clear...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path can be `/*` or just `*` --  but if you want to redirect everything to HTTPS, you don't need an extra rule... just edit the default rule to redirect all requests, instead of sending them to the target group.

Note also that on the right hand side, `#{port}` is wrong if you are redirecting from http to https -- you'll need to set the new port to 443... otherwise the balancer will try to redirect to `https://example.com:80` which is definitely not what you want.